# How do i make an if statement in excel return a blank?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I swear I've done this 100 times but now for some reason it doesn't work. Here is the excel formula I have:

=IF(AND(CurrentMonth>=9,CurrentYear>=2012),C5,"")

CurrentMonth is 10 and CurrentYear is 2012

C5 currently has no value, but is formatted as General. If I enter a ' into C5 the cell goes blank (result of the above If formula).

If I set the CurrentMonth < 9 or CurrentYear < 2012 the result of the formula is blank. Problem seems to be with the C column...blank value in the C column seen as a zero entry.

The resulting value is 0, but it should just be a blank/no value.
I have formatted the cells to be General, the cells with the formulas as well as the cell containing CurrentMonth and Current Year.

Thank you in advance for all help and recommendations. This community is the best.

Comment: This is normal behaviour - completely blank cells are normally returned as zeroes, VLOOKUP does that, for example, what sort of value is in C5 when populated?

Answer (score 3):

Your formula works rads currently: If greater than the current month AND year, then display C, otherwise blank.

If your question is how to handle the C column being blank so that the formula doesnt show 0 If your `AND` test passes, but C is empty.. then you can modify it like this:

```
=IF(AND(CurrentMonth>=9,CurrentYear>=2012,len(C5)>0),C5,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to modify the if statement:

```
=IF(AND(CurrentMonth>=9,CurrentYear>=2012),IF(ISBLANK(C5),"",C5),"")
```

This will make the cell "" if C5 is blank.

Answer (score 0):

this is normal behaviour, just try `=C5` and leave C5 blank, it will return 0

either use one of the previous solutions or format the result cell with custom number format: `[=0]"",General`